# Reject optional whitespaces after area code and before local number (US)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a regex that parses US phone numbers into 3 strings.

```
import re
s = '  916-2221111 ' # this also works'(916) 222-1111   '

reg_ph = re.match(r'^\s*\(?(\d{3})\)?-? *(\d{3})-? *-?(\d{4})', s)
if reg_ph:
    return reg_ph.groups()

else:
    raise ValueError ('not a valid phone number')
```

it works perfectly on the numbers:

```
'(916) 222-1111   '
'  916-2221111 '
```

Now I need to add an additional regex to generate a Value Error for numbers such as

```
s = '916 111-2222' # there are white spaces between the area code and a local number and NO ')'
```

I tried

```
reg_ph = re.match(r'^\s*\(?(\d{3})\)?\s*-? *(\d{3})-? *-?(\d{4})', s)
reg_ph = re.match(r'^\s*\(?(\d{3})\)?s*-? *(\d{3})-? *-?(\d{4})', s)
```

but non rejects the string in question

I will greatly appreciate any ideas. I am very new to Regex!

Comment: If I were you I would remove the parasitic characters and then validate the string with a simpler pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python re you could use a conditional to check for group 1 having the opening parenthesis.

If that is the case match the closing parenthesis, optional spaces and 3 digits. Else match `-` and 3 digits.

If you use re.match you can omit `^`

```
^\s*(\()?\d+(?(1)\)\s*\d{3}|-\d{3})-?\d{4}
```

If you want to match the whole string and trailing whitespace chars:

```
^\s*(\()?\d+(?(1)\)\s*\d{3}|-\d{3})-?\d{4}\s*$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(\()?` Optional group 1, match `(`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?` Conditional

  - `(1)\)\s*\d{3}` If group 1 exist, match the closing `)`,  optional whitespace chars and 3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `-?` Match optional -
  - `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
- `)` close conditional
- `-?\d{4}` Match optional - and 4 digits

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI95AW/1)

For example, using capture groups in the pattern to get the digits:

```
import re

strings = [' (916) 111-2222',' 916-2221111 ', '916 111-2222']
pattern =r'\s*(\()?(\d+)(?(1)\)\s*(\d{3})|-(\d{3}))-?(\d{4})\s*$'

for item in strings:
  m=re.match(pattern, item)
  if m:
    t = tuple(s for s in m.groups() if s is not None and s.isdigit())
    print(t)
  else:
    print("no match for " + item)
```

Output

```
('916', '111', '2222')
('916', '222', '1111')
no match for 916 111-2222
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##TY7NasMwEITveoohFLRqbIOaUmjA5A36AnUPplYSQfSDtDmUNM/uSq6h3dPuN8PsxC8@B7@bZ@tiSIxkhMicrD9l9HiXoFf9oqC1bp/KyEaigLoXpCEbyHL/6R8ijswmefRJDvmRBlIHGqatogNpNaiFTbfdXX2366La6rg936v4IIU4hgTLxsF6rGX2AnB9Mp0b@fNM65Nmsami2SNc9QBcevM1Xgxl1KBcU1x3SuEaM6nqLCjDB8Zb8Aajn5A7myd7skxKLSmxfGXiephLNvt/cOMDlhZL/Abb3xLz/AM)

Comment: @ The fourth bird - unfortunately none of strings work on the numbers that are already validated by the initial string.   Error:  Got ('(',) instead of ('916', '111', '2222') on the number '  (916)   111-2222  ' - it should have passed

Comment: @Toly the pattern matches, see https://ideone.com/niWp0l

Comment: @Toly if you want the numbers from the groups, see https://ideone.com/DzHUJD

Comment: one more question. I apologize. How to modify the code above to accept '9162221111' and reject: '916   111-2222', '916  222  1111', '(916-222-1111'

Comment: @toly You could use an alternation using `|` to also match 10 digits `^(?:\s*(\()?\d+(?(1)\)\s*\d{3}|-\d{3})-?\d{4}|\d{10})` See https://regex101.com/r/7pDkiY/1

Comment: when i try to unpack tuple (a,b,c = t) it gives an error - not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237218/discussion-between-toly-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: @toly the previous pattern was without the capture groups, this one is with the capture groups https://regex101.com/r/LN5wzc/1 or with 3 groups for the alternative as well https://regex101.com/r/oYPkFs/1