# Python regex US phone numbers - need to split '6502221111' into '650' '222' '1111'

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am very new to Regex.
I need to get the regex to manage US phone numbers

here is what I have:

```
r'\s*(\()?(\d+)(?(1)\)\s*(\d{3})|-(\d{3}))-?(\d{4})\s*$' # Thank you The Fourth Bird for your help!!
```

it splits any combo of phone numbers into 3 strings (see header)

One thing is does not do is splitting '9162223333' into '916', '222', '1111'

```
def par_ph (p):

    t1 = []
    t2 = []
    t3 = []
    pattern =r'\s*(\()?(\d+)(?(1)\)\s*(\d{3})|-(\d{3}))-?(\d{4})\s*$'

     pp=re.match(pattern, p)

    if pp:
        t = tuple(d for d in pp.groups() if d is not None and d.isdigit())
        t1,t2,t3 = t
        print(t1,t2,t3)

    else:
        print("ValueError " + p)
    
    return t1, t2,t3
```

OUTPUT:

```
()  (916) 111-2222
()  916-2221111 
ValueError 916 111-2222
()   (404)   555-1212  
() (404)555-1212  
()   404-555-1212 
()   404-5551212 
ValueError  4045551212
()     028-495-5163   
()     (818) 4266534     
()    285-4441519  
()    950-918-5781    
()    264-225-1686   
ValueError +1 (404) 555-3355
ValueError 404.555.3355
ValueError 404 555-3355
() 9165551111                   #INCORRECT since there is no separator in the string
ValueError (916-222-1111
ValueError 916 222  6666
ValueError 916   555-1111
```

Everything else works great!!

Much appreciate your help!!

Comment: Can you make the first `-` optional by adding `?` after it? `^\s*(\()?(\d+)(?(1)\)\s*(\d{3})|-?(\d{3}))-?(\d{4})\s*$`? See https://regex101.com/r/UjjM3B/1

Comment: It looks to be still the same thing as is dealt with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214625/. That  pattern is fine, but ``-`` must be optional.